# php - save username as variable then echo it elsewhere

Tags: php, authentication

I'm trying to modify a login form for a forum so that after logging in, it'll go, "Welcome, username."

Here's a chunk of the signin.php contents -

```
    if($errors == false){

    $user = $db->get_row("SELECT * FROM " . TABLES_PREFIX . "users WHERE email = '" . $_POST['username_or_email'] . "'  OR username = '" . $_POST['username_or_email'] . "' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1");

    if($user AND ($user->password == encode_password($_POST['password']))){
        if($user->status == 'pending'){
            $layout->AddContentById('alert', $layout->GetContent('alert'));
            $layout->AddContentById('alert_nature', ' alert-danger');
            $layout->AddContentById('alert_heading', '{{ST:error}}!');
            $layout->AddContentById('alert_message', '{{ST:your_account_not_activated}}');
        }elseif($user->status == 'banned'){
            $layout->AddContentById('alert', $layout->GetContent('alert'));
            $layout->AddContentById('alert_nature', ' alert-danger');
            $layout->AddContentById('alert_heading', '{{ST:error}}!');
            $layout->AddContentById('alert_message', '{{ST:your_account_is_banned}}');
        }else{
            Users_LoggedIn($user, isset($_POST['remember_me']));

            // **I'm guessing this is exactly where I should store the username as var**

            header('Location: '.FORUM_URL); // redirects to index.php
            exit;
        }
    }else{
        $layout->AddContentById('alert', $layout->GetContent('alert'));
        $layout->AddContentById('alert_nature', ' alert-danger');
        $layout->AddContentById('alert_heading', '{{ST:error}}!');
        $layout->AddContentById('alert_message', '{{ST:the_info_is_not_correct}}');
    }
}
```

And, then in index.php I guess I would add a line that goes something like (pseudo-code) -

```
echo '<div id="username">Welcome, '+$USERNAME+'</div>';
```

I've tried playing around with $_SESSION['username'] but I'm pretty useless in php, so any guidance would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: that is C/JS concatenation syntax `'+$USERNAME+'` you want to use dots.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: What does `Users_LoggedIn()` do? I imagine it saves a reference to the user so on subsequent requests the username is available. Try `print_r($_SESSION)` to see if it is somewhere in there, maybe it is in `$_SESSION['user']['username']` or something like that or maybe it just saves the user ID and you will need to fetch the user from the database (or modify the `Users_LoggedIn()` method to store the username).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sessions

In your login script:

```
session_start();
```

...

```
}else{
    Users_LoggedIn($user, isset($_POST['remember_me']));

    $_SESSION['Username'] = $user['username'];

    header('Location: '.FORUM_URL); // redirects to index.php
    exit;
}
```

Where you want to display it:

```
session_start();

echo '<div id="username">Welcome, '. $_SESSION['Username'] .'</div>';
```

More examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.php

Comment: do you know what your `$user` variable contains? you should try to view its contents using `var_dump()` or `print_r()`. maybe we're assigning the incorrect values to the session.

Comment: This is still too 'over my head', but thanks for giving it a shot.

Comment: no problem. these things are hard to grasp at first, just continue practicing. good luck mate.